# Matlab file loading error

Tags: matlab, ascii

This is what the file I am trying to load looks like. It is a combination of both hex and ascii. What I want to do is load the data and convert the ASCII into a hex format. However, when I try to load the data into matlab it doesn't recognize a lot of the ASCII characters, and leaves them blank as a result. I have tried using importdata( ) as well as fopen( ) and fgetl( ), but both result in the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    736020.582471  Å% ÅÀ
    736020.582471  Å2 Å9
    736020.582471  Å# Å¡
    736020.582471  Å8 År
    736020.582471  Å  Åó
    736020.582471  Å= Åñ
    736020.582472  Å  ÅX
    736020.582472  Å; Å≈
    736020.582472  Å¬ Å@
    736020.582472  Å7 ÅÀ
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me learn something here, but the example text in your post, is that the file you are trying to load? Or is that what Matlab came up with? Have you tried fscanf()?